# NullPointerException is occurring with createNamedQuery and then persistence unit logins successfully

Tags: jpa, ejb, eclipselink

I can't seem to solve this issue. I have tried googling but can't put the pieces together to solve it. I have the following stack trace:

```
Warning:   java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.ServerPlatformUtils.createServerPlatform(ServerPlatformUtils.java:99)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.init(SessionManager.java:77)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.<clinit>(SessionManager.java:71)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.addSessionToGlobalSessionManager(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:907)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.initSession(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2671)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:675)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:318)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:197)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:521)
at session.CategoryFacade.findRandom(CategoryFacade.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173.findRandom(Unknown Source)
at session.__EJB31_Generated__CategoryFacade__Intf____Bean__.findRandom(Unknown Source)
at actions.ActionFacade.setFeaturedCategories(ActionFacade.java:82)
at actions.HomeAction.execute(HomeAction.java:16)
at controller.ControllerServlet.service(ControllerServlet.java:65)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Info:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258
Info: /file:/Users/csexton/NetBeansProjects/ReadersParadise/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_AffableBeanPU login successful
```

So if you look at the last two lines my persistent unit isn't logging in until I try to use the entity manager. If I do another query after the first one, everything is good, no errors, nothing......Error occurs on the createNamedQuery. The query exists and matches the exact name. I can call the same method twice and the first one causes a NPE but the second one works fine.

```
@Stateless(name="CategoryFacade")
public class CategoryFacade extends AbstractFacade<Category> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "AffableBeanPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public CategoryFacade() {
        super(Category.class);
    }

    public List<Category> findRandom(int limit) {
        return getEntityManager()
                .createNamedQuery("Category.findRandomByLimit")
                .setParameter(1, limit)
                .getResultList();
    }
}
```

I am doing a jndi lookup for the class

```
public class ActionFacade implements AutoCloseable {

  private static ThreadLocal<ActionFacade> instance = new ThreadLocal<>();

  private HttpServletRequest request;
  private HttpSession session;

  private CategoryFacade categoryFacade;
  private BookFacade bookFacade;
  private OrderManager orderManager;

  private ShoppingCart cart;


  public ActionFacade(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
    this.session = request.getSession();

    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        this.categoryFacade = (CategoryFacade) ctx.lookup(
                "java:global/ReadersParadise/CategoryFacade!session.CategoryFacade");
        System.out.print("JNDI lookup complete.");
        this.bookFacade = (BookFacade) ctx.lookup(
                "java:global/ReadersParadise/BookFacade!session.BookFacade");
        this.orderManager = (OrderManager) ctx.lookup(
                "java:global/ReadersParadise/OrderManager!session.OrderManager");
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
  }


  public static ActionFacade create(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ActionFacade facade = new ActionFacade(request);
    instance.set(facade);
    return facade;
  }


  public static ActionFacade getCurrentInstance() {
    return instance.get();
  }


  @Override
  public void close() {
    instance.remove();
  }

  public void setSelectedCategory() {
      String categoryName = request.getParameter("category");

      Category selectedCategory = categoryFacade.findByName(categoryName);

      if (selectedCategory == null) {
          selectedCategory = categoryFacade.find(1);
      }
      session.setAttribute("selectedCategory", selectedCategory);

      Collection<Book> categoryBooks = selectedCategory.getBookCollection();
      session.setAttribute("categoryBooks", categoryBooks);
   }

   public void setAllCategories() {
      request.setAttribute("categories", categoryFacade.findAll());
   }
}
```

Then in my servlet I am using the ActionFacade like this....

```
try(ActionFacade facade = ActionFacade.create(request)) {
    Action action = ActionFactory.getAction(request);
    String view = action.execute(facade);
    System.out.println(request.getServletPath());
    if (request.getServletPath().equals("") || view.equals(request.getServletPath().substring(1))) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/" + view + ".jsp").forward(request, response);
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(view); 
    }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ServletException("Executing action failed.", e);
}
```

This is the category entity

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.name= :name")
})
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "Category.findRandomByLimit", 
        query = "SELECT * FROM Category ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?1")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category")
    private Collection<Book> bookCollection;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Category(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Book> getBookCollection() {
        return bookCollection;
    }

    public void setBookCollection(Collection<Book> bookCollection) {
        this.bookCollection = bookCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Category)) {
            return false;
        }
        Category other = (Category) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Category[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

Category Action Class which uses the ActionFacade

```
public class CategoryAction implements Action {

    @Override
    public String execute(ActionFacade facade) throws Exception {
        facade.setSelectedCategory();
        facade.setAllCategories();
        return "category";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is just a `warning`, not an exception or error... (of course, it is still unbeautiful)

Comment: what is causing it?

Comment: I'd suggest not to mix Container Managed Bean injection using CDI/EJB annotation with JNDI lookups.

Comment: can you provide a demonstration or reference a tutorial on an alternative? I am not that experienced in Java EE...

Comment: Where is the code for `ActionFacade.setFeaturedCategories`

Comment: I removed it from the ActionFacade class when I posted just because it was irrelevant to the problem. Tried to keep code to a minimal. Its just a method that takes the request object and sets a few parameters.

Comment: @SteveC please see the edit above. I included the CategoryAction Class and updated the ActionFacade Class....

Comment: What are you using for an application server?

Comment: @SteveC Glassfish 4.1.1

Comment: @AsSiDe: Please explain, why you suggest this [*I'd suggest not to mix Container Managed Bean injection using CDI/EJB annotation with JNDI lookups.*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a problem of Glassfish 4.1.1 described here:
https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21468

According this, it may help, if you add

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="Glassfish"/>
```

to your `persistence.xml`